# Allow duplicate email address for Joomla 2.5 user registration

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using `Joomla 2.5` and it is not giving duplicate email address for the user registration.

But I want create accounts using same email address. I know I've to edit the core and It may be not an issue because I'm not going to update the Joomla in future.

How can I do that core hack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little shocked that you said you will never update Joomla in the future. 2.5 as you may not know will reach EOL (end of life) in December this year, therefore a lot of extension developers will stop support and developing extensions for 2.5, therefore if you have any issues, you may run into problems.

Secondly, please just don't do a core hack, it's the most awful thing one can do. I needn't explain why.

I would simply suggest using an extension such as [User Same Email](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/24599)

Comment: That plugin seemed to work on the back end but not the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lodder on his point of view that a "core hack" is bad, and that using an extension like "Users Same Email" (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/24599) is better.

But however, if really you need so, you can have a look at the hack propose on the Joomla forum :
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2424367

It explain where to change the code in the \libraries\joomla\database\table\user.php file, to have the possibility to register many user with the same email.

Comment: That plugin seemed to work on the back end but not the front end.